# Difference between Verilog and SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Can you explain me what is major differences between Verilog, SystemVerilog, Verilog 1995 and Verilog 2001. I am using `xilinx 14.1` edition and want to know whether it supports Verilog 2001.

How can I check for confirmation? Is there anything I should modify in settings?

Answer (score 2):

Page 2 of this [SystemVerilog paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/DAC2009_SystemVerilog_Update_Part2_SutherlandHDL.pdf) has a nice chart showing the differences between Verilog 1995, 2001 and SystemVerilog.

Answer (score 0):

System Verilog is updated version of Verilog that have C like programming.  Even classes

```
class Triangle; 
   ... 
   function new()
   ... // all initializations go here
   endfunction
   ...
endclass
```